# Cast object to type from another assembly

Tags: c#, .net, dll, reflection, .net-assembly

I have 3 projects: 2 are class libraries and 1 is console app:

1. class library "AnimalManagers". In AnimalManagers is

   ```
   public interface AnimalAgressiveBase{
         string Bark<TAnimal>(TAnimal animal);
   }
   public abstract class AnimalAgressive<TEnemy> : AnimalAggresiveBase {
         public abstract string BarkAtEnemy(TEnemy enemy);

         public string Bark<TAnimal>(TAnimal animal){
               return BarkAtEnemy((TEnemy)animal);// <---- Invalid cast exception even if type of object "animal" is Cat and we call this method from Dog class
         }
   }

   public class AnimalManager {

      public void WatchAnimal<TAnimalModel>
          (TAnimalModel animalModel) { //<-- in example, animalModel is Cat("lucy")

             var aggresiveAnimalDog = GetAgresiveAnimal(); //<-- returns object from dynamically loaded class Dog so this is basicaly new Dog() if animal models library class were referenced
             if(aggresiveAnimalData != null) aggresiveAnimalDog .Bark(animalModel);
      }
      public AnimalAgressiveBase GetAgresiveAnimal(){
          Assembly.LoadFrom("..\\AnimalModels.dll");
          ....
          return aggresiveAnimal; //In This case Dog because he implements correct interface
      }
   }
   ```
2. class library "AnimalModels" In AnimalModels are model classes Cat and Dog

   ```
   public class Cat {
        public string Name {get;set;}

   }

   public class Dog : AnimalAgressive<Cat> {
       public override string BarkAtEnemy(Cat enemy){return enemy.Name;}
   }
   ```

Both libraries are referenced in ConsoleApp "Zoo" , and I get invalid type exception when I call

```
var manager = new AnimalManager();
var manager.WatchAnimal(new Cat{Name="lucy"});
```

I got invalid cast exception because of dynamically loaded assembly types doesnt coresspond with referenced types, even if they got same AssemblyQualifiedName.

Any solutions? Goal is to load assembly get types that implements known interface (ex: AnimalAggressiveBase) and call method that I pass data of some type.

Comment: new Cat(){Name="lucy"}

Answer (score 0):

Your main issue seems to be that you do not have anything representing your animals in the type system. How does your class `Cat` tie in with the rest of your class hierarchy?

```
public void WatchAnimal<TAnimalModel>
   (TAnimalModel animalModel) { ... }
```

Basically here `TAnimalModel` can be *anything*; I could pass in a `string` an `int` or a `Stream` and the compiler wouldn't complain. You need to constaint `TAnimalModel` to what you are *really* expecting so that the compiler can reason about what you can do or not do with `animalModel`:

```
public void WatchAnimal<TAnimalModel>
   (TAnimalModel animalModel) { ... } where TAnimalModel: AnimalBase
```

`AnimalBase` can be an abstract base class, a regular base class, an interface, what have you. The only condition is that all your animal models need to implement it:

```
public class Cat: AnimalBase { ... }.
```

The same thing happens with the following method:

```
public abstract class AnimalAgressive<TEnemy> : AnimalAggresiveBase { ... }
```

Again, here `TEnemy` can be anything. That is why you are getting a compile time error in `(TEnemy)animal`. The compiler can't verify that the cast is valid and therefore disallows it; *you* know that `TEnemy` will be an animal but you haven't told the compiler... so *tell* the compiler adding a constaint:

```
public abstract class AnimalAgressive<TEnemy> : AnimalAggresiveBase where TEnemy: AnimalBase { ... }
```

Comment: Yes I agree that this is straightforward and well designed architecture. But due to other circumstances like: Model classes ex. Cat, cannot derive from other classes (customer specific requirements)

Comment: @user2977027 Then how is generics going to help you exactly? If you can't *know* anything about the incoming animal, don't use generics, its pointless; simply use a non generic approach: `object` and reflection or simply `dynamic`. Both can explode in your face in runtime but if thats the way your client wants it...

Answer (score 0):

Performance expensive solution IMHO.

```
[EDIT TO CLASS]

public abstract class AnimalAgressive<TEnemy> : AnimalAggresiveBase where TEnemy : class, new(){

[EDIT TO METHOD]
public string Bark<TAnimal>(TAnimal animal){
            var typeAnimal = typeof(TAnimal);
            var typeEnemy = typeof(TEnemy);

            var propsAnimal = typeData.GetProperties();
            var propsEnemy = typeGener.GetProperties();

            var obj = new T();

            foreach (var propertyInfo in propsAnimal)
            {
                var value = propertyInfo.GetValue(dataObject);
                try
                {
                    var propEnemy  = propsEnemy.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.Equals(propertyInfo.Name, StringComparison.CurrentCulture));
                    propGener?.SetValue(obj, value, null);
                }
                catch (Exception)
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return Bark(obj.Name);
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommed MEF  here.

```
public interface IAnimalAgressive<in TAnimal>
{
    string Bark(TAnimal animal);
}

public abstract class AnimalAggressiveBase<TEnemy> : IAnimalAgressive<TEnemy>
{
    public abstract string BarkAtEnemy(TEnemy enemy);
    public string Bark(TEnemy enemy)
    {
        return BarkAtEnemy(enemy);
    }
}
```

your Animal manager then becomes:

```
public class AnimalManager
{
    public void WatchAnimal<TAggressiveAnimal, TAnimal>
        (TAggressiveAnimal aggressive, TAnimal enemy)
        where TAggressiveAnimal : IAnimalAgressive<TAnimal>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(aggressive.Bark(enemy));
    }
}
```

Now its the responsibility of the Dog and Cat to conform to the AnimalManager expectations, I will keep it simple for now:

```
using System.ComponentModel.Composition;
namespace AnimalModels
{
    [Export(typeof(Cat))]
    public class Cat
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
}
```

and Dog becomes:

```
using AnimalManagers;
using System.ComponentModel.Composition;
namespace AnimalModels
{
    [Export(typeof(AnimalAggressiveBase<Cat>))]
    public class Dog : AnimalAggressiveBase<Cat>
    {
        public override string BarkAtEnemy(Cat enemy)
        {
            return enemy.Name;
        }
    }
}
```

The trick now is to compose the whole catalog of relevant types, so for our console app, we create another type for managing these relationships from the catalog of types we have exported:

```
public class TypeManager
{
    public void Compose()
    {
        try
        {
            var directoryPath = Path.GetFullPath(".");
            var aggregateCatalog = new AggregateCatalog();
            aggregateCatalog.Catalogs.Add(new DirectoryCatalog(directoryPath, "*.dll"));

            //Create the composition container
            var container = new CompositionContainer(aggregateCatalog);

            container.ComposeParts(this);

            var cat = container.GetExportedValue<Cat>();
            cat.Name = "lucy";
            var dog = container.GetExportedValue<AnimalAggressiveBase<Cat>>();
            var manager = new AnimalManager();
            manager.WatchAnimal(dog, cat);
        }
        catch (CompositionException compositionException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(compositionException.ToString());
            throw;
        }


    }
}
```

now all we need to do is to run the Main method like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        TypeManager tm = new TypeManager();

        tm.Compose();
    }
```

Now the exported types will automatically get created in the typemanager and we dont have to worry about reflection.

Answer (score -1):

```
public interface AnimalAgressiveBase<TAnimal>
{
    string Bark(TAnimal animal);
}

public abstract class AnimalAgressive<TEnemy, TAnimal> : AnimalAgressiveBase<TAnimal> where TEnemy : TAnimal
{
    public abstract string BarkAtEnemy(TEnemy enemy);

    public string Bark(TAnimal animal)
    {
        return BarkAtEnemy((TEnemy)animal);
    }
}
```